# Windows to look like Mac

Tags: mac, windows-vista, themes, styles

Does anybody know any way to make my windows computer running vista look like a mac?

Comment: Just get the real thing :p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Rocketdock (Stardock was hinky on my P4), & put the taskbar on the top of the screen.  If you can easily skin Vista like you can XP, [LutetumGUI](http://-kol.deviantart.com/art/LutetiumGUI-13119501) looks great on the various machines I've tried it on.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions out there, but if you do not mind paying, I think the best one is [Stardock Window Blinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/) - If you do not mind a few limitations, you may get away with just using the free version.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Leopard Transformation Pack](http://hydrattz.deviantart.com/art/Leopard-Transformation-Pack-1-82126691) although I'm a bit weary about using transformation packs. make sure you've created a restore point before moving ahead.