# Is there any way to get a Windows PC to look like Mac?

Tags: windows, mac, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows to look like Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/79380/windows-to-look-like-mac)

I am running Windows 7 and I want to make my desktop look something like this:

What software can I use to achieve these effects:

- Have a translucent dock on the bottom
- Have a bar at the top of the screen, which is also translucent.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google usually helps:
http://www.google.com/#hl=en&xhr=t&q=snow+leopard+theme+windows+7

The first listing came to this page:
http://www.mascobz.com/best-snow-leopard-transformation-pack-for-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

I also did a google search for "Mac skin for windows 7", giving a different result.

http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/22/mac-theme-for-windows-7/